# Similar in Access a function in excel TEXT(,)

Tags: ms-access

In Excel if a cell contains 60 (as required hours) another cell container 8 (shift hours) and if in the third cell I type `=TEXT(60/8,"[h]:min:sec")`, then the result I will get is `180:00:00`.

So if my start-date is `1-Jan-2019` and I add to it `180:00:00` than the finish date will be `08-01-2019`. Basically what it means is that the required man hours is 60 and each day if we are going to work for 8 hours than we need total of 180 hours to complete that work. Need similar function in access.

Comment: please format your text properly in your next question

Answer (score 0):

You can use *DateAdd*:

```
DateStart = #2019-01-01#
Days = 60 / 8        ' 7.5
Hours = Days * 24    ' 180

DateEnd = DateAdd("h", Hours, DateStart)   ' -> 2019-01-08 12:00:00
```